# A problem related to analytic function

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, analytic-functions, zeroes

Let, $z,w\in \mathbb{C}$. Let, $f(z)$ be an analytic function in $|z|<1$. Define, $f(z)= g(w)$ where $g(w)$ is analytic function in $\Re(w)>1/2$ and $w=\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ .

**Question** Prove that $$\sum_{|\alpha|<1, f(\alpha)=0}\log\frac{1}{|\alpha|^2}= 
 \sum_{\Re(\rho)>1/2, g(\rho)=0}\log\frac{|\rho|}{|1-\rho|} $$
where in both the sums, the zeros of multiplicity $k$ are counted $k$ times.

**Attempt**
Since $f(z)$ is an analytic function in $|z|<1$, so it has countably many zeros in $|z|<1$. Define a set $A=\{\alpha\in \mathbb{C}\mid |\alpha|<1,f(\alpha)=0\}$

Since , $f(\alpha)=g\left(\frac{1}{1+\alpha^2}\right)$. So, $\alpha\in A $ if and only if $-\alpha\in A$. Thus, let $\alpha_i$ be the zero with multiplicity $m_i$, $i=1,2,...$ $A=\{(\alpha_1)^{m_1},(-\alpha_1)^{m_1},(\alpha_2)^{m_2},(-\alpha_2)^{m_2},... \}$ Also, $g(w)$ is analytic in $\Re(w)>1/2$  and $\rho_i=\frac{1}{1+\alpha_i^2}$so define the set of its countable zeros as
$B=\{(\rho_1)^{m_1},(\rho_1)^{m_1},(\rho_2)^{m_2},(\rho_2)^{m_2}...\}$
$B=\{(\rho_1)^{2m_1},(\rho_2)^{2m_2},...\}$
$$\sum_{|\alpha|<1,f(\alpha)=0}\log\frac{1}{|\alpha|^2}=2m_1\log\frac{1}{|\alpha_1|^2}+  2m_2\log\frac{1}{|\alpha_2|^2}+...  $$
$$\sum_{\Re(\rho)>1/2, g(\rho)=0}\log\frac{|\rho|}{|1-\rho|}=\log\frac{|\rho_1|}{|1-\rho_1|}+ \log\frac{|\rho_2|}{|1-\rho_2|}+...  $$ Also , $\rho_i=\frac{1}{1+\alpha_i^2}$ so we get,$$\sum_{\Re(\rho)>1/2, g(\rho)=0}\log\frac{|\rho|}{|1-\rho|}= 2m_1\log\frac{1}{|\alpha_1|^2}+  2m_2\log\frac{1}{|\alpha_2|^2}+...   $$ Hence, $$\sum_{|\alpha|<1, f(\alpha)=0}\log\frac{1}{|\alpha|^2}= 
 \sum_{\Re(\rho)>1/2, g(\rho)=0}\log\frac{|\rho|}{|1-\rho|} $$

Comment: @YCor Thanks for the edit. Is my reasoning correct? Any mathematical mistakes?

Comment: @YCor Is everything correct? Any mistakes?

Comment: Please anyone answer. Is there an error? Any other way of doing it?

Comment: Please comment/answer. I will happily give it a check mark